# Apply function on the Unique value of a Column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

For a Function :-

```
def chief_string(title):
    if 'chief' in title.lower():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

So if I want the Sum of customers where the Job title contains 'chief', then it would be by :-

```
sum(sal['JobTitle'].apply(lambda x: chief_string(x)))
```

However when I want to use apply() on Unique values of column then it doesn't work to get unique Job titles containing 'chief' :-

```
sal['JobTitle'].unique.apply(lambda x: chief_string(x))
```

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

As reported here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html `unique` return an array, that does not have an `apply` method.

A possible solution can be

```
list(filter(chief_string, sal['JobTitle'].unique())
```

Comment: Hi Andrea , Thanks for reply. Above solution doesn't provide the exact 'JobTitle' but a single list of Boolean values!!

Comment: Hi! It was not so clear... I changed the answer using filter. Hope this solve the issue